# Uninitialized Structures c

Tags: c

i'm having trouble whit this code. I get the error " uninitialized local variable "question1" used", I'm new to c and I'm really trying to learn. I'm trying to build a quiz program where i can use both Structures and textfile. i'm just staring but the error gets in the way !!

the code is !

```
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define max 70
struct question{
    char *questions;
    char *alter1;
    char *alter2;
    char *alter3;
    char *alter4;
    char correct;
};


int main(){

char *m;
struct question question1;
struct question Alt1;



    question1.questions[max] = "what is my name?A:Haidar?B:Ali?C:Hagob?D:Aws?";
    Alt1.alter1 = 'A';
    Alt1.alter2 = 'B';
    Alt1.alter3 = 'C';
    Alt1.alter4 = 'D';
    Alt1.correct;
    m = question1.questions[max];
    printf("%s\n", *m);
    scanf("%c", &Alt1.correct);

    if (Alt1.correct == Alt1.alter1);
    {
        print("right you have won\n");
    }

    if ((Alt1.correct) != Alt1.alter1); {

        printf("sorry\n");
    }



    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: You didn't give `question1` an initial value.

Comment: how do i do that ? :)

Comment: Well one way would be to give it an initial value of `{"","","","","",''}` (5 strings and 1 char).

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense at all. It is filled with several problems. This is what the correct code would look like: [ideone](http://ideone.com/LGR63v)

Answer (score 0):

`question1.questions` is a `char` pointer. When you write `question1.questions[max]` you are saying "take the current value of the pointer, add (50 times the length of one `char`) to it, and dereference the result.

But `question1.questions` was never given an initial value. It is an uninitialized pointer, hence it doesn't point anywhere. You can't, therefore, dereference it.

Since you say it is supposed to be an array of strings, not a single string, your structure definition should look like:

```
#define max 70
struct question{
    char *questions[max];
    char *alter1;
    char *alter2;
    char *alter3;
    char *alter4;
    char correct;
};
```

Then `questions[0]` would refer to the FIRST string. `questions[max-1]` would be the LAST string.  `questions[max]` would be an error, past the end of the array.

Comment: it's supposed to be an array of strings !

Comment: I did that actually but then i got two errors saying " Unresolved external & Unresolved external symbol, print reference in main function  "

Comment: @HaidarWahid: Read the error message, don't be helpless. You used `print`, there is no function named `print`. It told you exactly what was wrong. Hint: You typoed a legit function name.

Comment: haha no i dont have print anywhere i said i was new to the language no stupid ;)@ShadowRanger